# Calculate polynomial equation for curve based on known gradient?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the polynomial equation representing a curve. I only know that the gradient is represented by a linear equation.

To be more specific: I know that the gradient of the curve increases by $1$ (degree, if that is important?) every $10$ units. I.e. at $x=0$ it is $0$. At $x=10$ it is $1$, at $x=20$ the inclination of the gradient is $2$ (again, degree if that matters). If I go by $y=ax$, I get gradient $a$ as being $0.1$, and therefor my equation representing the gradient is $y=0.1*x$.

Now I know that the gradient is the derivative of the curve. So the equation of the curve should be the integral of the gradient equation, which is $Y=(a/2)*x^2$, and with $a=0.1$ it should be $Y=0.05*x^2$. But the resulting curve doesn't fit at all. It is much too steep. The graphical solution (created by using 10 segments of each 10 units) yields ca. $f(x=100)=~10$.

What am I overseeing?

Comment: The curve is starting from $(0, 0)$, so $C$ should be $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I can't just consider an angle as an arbitrary number. I actually had to use trigonometric functions to calculate hypothenuse, opposite side, and adjacent side of the triangle to make it work.